# JQuery to fire when <a> anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I would like a alert message to be displayed telling me what href link was selected when
an anchor tag was clicked

can this be done with jquery

I was hoping

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert(this.href);
});
```

would do it

```
<a href="/Eureka/Home.aspx" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Home</a>
<a href="/Eureka/IPAQ/IPAQAssignments.asp" target="_parent"   onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">IPAQ Summary</a>
<a href="https://www.askcnet.com/cgi-bin/wonderdesk/wonderdesk.cgi" target="_new" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Eureka System Support</a>
<a href="/Eureka/Logout.aspx" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Logout</a>
```

the test page below doesn't seem to fire do i have the jquery set

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JScripts/jquery.tooltip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JScripts/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JScripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); //if you want to prevent from visiting the link
alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="/Eureka/Home.aspx" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Home</a><br>
<a href="/Eureka/IPAQ/IPAQAssignments.asp" target="_parent"   onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">IPAQ Summary</a><br>
<a href="https://www.askcnet.com/cgi-bin/wonderdesk/wonderdesk.cgi" target="_new" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Eureka System Support</a><br>
<a href="/Eureka/Logout.aspx" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Logout</a><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried that? Does that work? What is the problem then?

Comment: Why did you tag **ASP.Net**?

Comment: I am seeing an extra double quote after your `onClick`. You have to remove that.

Comment: Are you binding it after the elements are added to the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to show an alert prior to moving on you could show the alert, prevent default (which would just follow the link immediately), and then assign the window location to the href.

*alert*

```
$('a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert(this.href);
 window.location = this.href;
});
```

Alternatively, you could use confirm instead of alert

*confirm*

```
$('a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if(confirm(this.href))
  window.location = this.href;
});
```

Comment: Even without `preventDefault` it will show the alert prior to the redirect. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/dcZ3K/

OP has the question as well as the answer. He have not realized that.

Comment: Though, +1 for the procedural way.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you'll want to do something like this:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //if you want to prevent from visiting the link
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: ok my anchors are embedded in div tags    <div style=display:none; class="clsMenu" id="divMenuSystem">
 <div style=margin:0,0,0,0;>
  <a href="/Eureka/Home.aspx" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">Home</a>
 </div>
 <div style=margin:0,0,0,0;>
  <a href="/Eureka/IPAQ/IPAQAssignments.asp" target="_parent" onClick="closeAllSubMenus();"">IPAQ Summary</a>
 </div>
</div>